# Putting methods into an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to put these Methods into an ArrayList, but I can't figure out how to do that. I'm using NetBeans, and the program is going to be a GUI.

Here is my code:

```
public class canada150Tour extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList <String> mcQuestions = new ArrayList(); //This is the array I want to put the below methods into.


    private void questionFredricton(){
        outputTextQuestion.append("Where is Fredricton located?");

        displayQuestions.append("New Brunswick");        
    }
    private void questionRegina(){
        outputTextQuestion.setText("Where is Regina located?");

        displayQuestions.append("Saskatchewan");

    }
    private void questionOttawa(){
        outputTextQuestion.setText("Where is Ottawa located?");

        displayQuestions.append("Ontario");
    }
    private void questionHalifax(){
        outputTextQuestion.setText("Where is Halifax located?");

        displayQuestions.append("Nova Scotia");
    }
    private void questionQuebecCity(){
        outputTextQuestion.setText("Where is Quebec City located?");

        displayQuestions.append("Quebec");
    }
    private void questionEdmonton(){
        outputTextQuestion.setText("Where is Edmonton located?");

        displayQuestions.append("Alberta");
    }
    private void questionCharlottetown(){
        outputTextQuestion.setText("Where is Charlottetown located?");

        displayQuestions.append("Prince Edward Island");
    }
    private void questionVictoria(){
        outputTextQuestion.setText("Where is Victoria located?");

        displayQuestions.append("British Columbia");
    }
    private void questionIqaluit(){
        outputTextQuestion.setText("Where is Iqaluit located?");

        displayQuestions.append("Nunavut");
    }
    private void questionWhitehorse(){
        //outputTextQuestion.setText("Where is Whitehorse located?");

        displayQuestions.append("Yukon");
    }
    private void questionWinnipeg(){
        outputTextQuestion.setText("Where is Winnipeg located?");

        displayQuestions.append("Manitoba");
    }
```

I've tried:

```
Collections.addAll(mcQuestions, questionFredricton(), questionRegina());
```

And so on for all the methods, but obviously that isn't working.

I get a compiling error when I'm trying to add to the ArrayList (above):

> 'void' type not allowed here

I'm fairly new to Java, so still learning.

**EDIT:**
This will eventually be a multiple choice quiz.  I essentially want to the put the methods into an array so I can chose methods randomly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you need sounds to me like a Hashmap to map strings to QuestionAnswer class!

Comment: You can't add method in `ArrayList`

Comment: When you say 'put the methods in the ArrayList', what do you mean? What do you want the list to have in it after you've done this?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan you technically can by using method references. The list would then be an `ArrayList<Runnable>` and you can add methods to it using `mcQuestions.add(this:: questionFredricton)`.

Comment: What's the goal of adding these methods to a list ? By using Java Reflection, you can get Method object and you can call this method on a Object but it is a bit difficult to use...

Comment: @Palle can you elaborate it, I've compiler error, seems syntax inappropriate

Comment: I think perhaps you should just stick to filling an ArrayList (or List object) with your question/answers and forget about all those methods altogether. With a 2D ArrayList (List) you can also later append other pertinent information like Population, Coordinates, etc, etc. You can then randomly choose which question element to display from the List. The List could also be filled from file or Database data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `ArrayList` as an argument to methods in order to add elements inside it, e.g.:

```
private void questionFredricton(ArrayList <String> mcQuestions){
    mcQuestions.add("Where is Fredricton located?");
}
```

And call the method like this:

```
ArrayList <String> mcQuestions = new ArrayList();
questionFredricton(mcQuestions);
```

Also, it seems you need to store the pair of questions and answers here, in which case, it's better to use `HashMap`, e.g.:

```
private void questionFredricton(Map<String, String> questions){
    questions.put("Where is Fredricton located?", "New Brunswick");
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Map<String, String> questions = new HashMap<>();
questionFredricton(questions);
```

This way, you will be able to store both questions and answers. `questions.keySet()` will give you list of all the questions and `questions.get("<questions>")` will give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your method should return a `String` if you want to add a `String` in a `ArrayList` of `String`.
But in fact I don't think that you should do it because you needs both Question and Response. It seems better to have a List of `QuestionAndResponse` rather than two `List` of String.
A  `QuestionAndResponse`  could contain the text of the question but also the text of the expected response.

```
public class QuestionAndResponse{
     public QuestionAndResponse(String question, String response){
         this.question = question;  
         this.response = response;
     }
     // getters for fields
}
```

So you could declare the List :

```
List <QuestionAndResponse> mcQuestionsResponses = new ArrayList<>();
```

And you could replace this :

```
private void questionFredricton(){
    outputTextQuestion.append("Where is Fredricton located?");
    displayQuestions.append("New Brunswick");        
}
```

by:

```
private QuestionAndResponse questionFredricton(){
    return new QuestionAndResponse("Where is Fredricton located?","New Brunswick");
}
```

Now you can have a Canada150Tour (note the uppercase for the first letter to follow the naming conventions) constructor that uses them :

```
public class Canada150Tour extends JFrame {
    List <QuestionAndResponse> mcQuestionsResponses;
       ...
    public Canada150Tour(){
         mcQuestionsResponses = new ArrayList<>(); 
         mcQuestionsResponses.add(questionFredricton());
    }

     private QuestionAndResponse questionFredricton(){
        return new QuestionAndResponse("Where is Fredricton located?",
                                        "New Brunswick");
     }
}
```